# I cannot update Spyder on Anaconda, updating takes forever

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, spyder

I want to install a version of Spyder higher than 5.1.5 on Anaconda 2.3.0. I have updated anaconda using either the pop up of anaconda or using CMD and typing

```
conda update --all
```

or

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

After I updated Anaconda, I tried to update spyder. I made several attemps:

I used the wheel next to spyder and did "update spyder". That took very long, ended after more than one hour but Spyder is still version 5.1.5. I then used the wheel to manually select an install version, I picked one of the latest two, 5.2.2. However even after spending more than 3 hours, the update is not over. It's still running. "Upgrading application spyder on C:\my path" with a loading circle running below Spyder's icon and "Spyder" on the navigator.

I also tried to remove spyder before reinstalling it with:

```
conda remove spyder
conda remove python-language-server
conda update anaconda
conda install spyder=5.2.2
```

But it stuck at the last step with conflicts running for more than 6 hours with no end in sight.

I uninstalled anaconda, started with a fresh install and tried the same things, after a fresh install I tried only doing: conda install spyder=5.2.2, but that didn't work, it also ran for more than 5 hours helplessly.

I tried to remove spyder from the navigator by uninstalling it individually before reinstalling spyder from the 5.2.2 directly but it didn't work either.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: 24 hrs later, and it's still supposedly updating. This solution did not work for me (to upgrade to Spyder 5.3.3).

I'm attempting this for myself right now, as I'm having the same trouble.

Try updating Anaconda Navigator first, then using it to upgrade Spyder to the most recent version.. but instead of clicking “Update application” which still doesn’t quite work, click on “Install specific version” and choose the latest version of Spyder.

https://mathtuition88.com/2020/09/08/updating-spyder-takes-forever/